# Measuring execution time with clock in sec in C not working

Tags: c, linux, unix, time, clock

I'm trying to measure execution time in C using `clock()` under linux using the following:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  clock_t begin, end;
  begin = clock();
  sleep(2);
  end = clock();
  double spent = ((double)(end-begin)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("%ld %ld, spent: %f\n", begin, end, spent);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
1254 1296, spent: 0.000042
```

The documentation says to divide the clock time by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to get the execution time in sec, but this seems pretty incorrect for a 2sec `sleep`.

What's the problem?

Comment: `%f` is for `double`, just FYI.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yeas it is, like the variable time_spent.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, C variadic functions do certain promotions automatically. One of those is from float to double. Using %f for floats isn't optimal, but it isn't exactly an error either. The same goes for print chars with %d.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh did you miss the first two format specifiers?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I am obviously failing to see your point. I thought it was that he was using %f for float type, but he wasn't. He prints two signed longs with two %ld (as it should), and a double with %f (again, correctly). I do not understand what your reservation was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleeping takes almost no execution time. The program just has to schedule its wakeup and then put itself to sleep. While it's asleep, it is not executing. When it's woken up, it doesn't have to do anything at all. That all takes a very tiny fraction of a second.

It doesn't take more execution time to sleep longer. So the fact that there's a 2 second period when the program is not executing has no effect.

Comment: Ok thank you, and how can I measure the time sleeping? That's what I need in fact.

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto You could use `clock_gettime` and `CLOCK_MONOLITHIC` to get the current time; this will work like you expect it to (keep in mind it's a POSIX thing; on Windows you could use `GetTickCount` or `QueryPerformanceCounter`, if you need portability).

Answer (score 1):

`clock` measures CPU time (in Linux at least). A sleeping process consumes no CPU time.

If you want to measure a time interval as if with a stopwatch, regardless of what your process is doing, use `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Comment: Thank you that's what I needed originally.

Answer (score 0):

`man clock()` has the answer:

`The clock() function returns an approximation of processor time used by the program.`

Which clearly tells that `clock()` returns the processor time used by the program, not what you were expecting the total run time of the program which is typically done using `gettimeofday`.